# error when running chrome profile with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

i have a code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default")
drive = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\ggauto\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

when i running i get error:

```
DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
drive = webdriver.Chrome(

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57654/devtools/browser/217fefe3-72fa-4feb-b95a-964e883954f1
PS C:\Users\Administrator> [13504:11156:0613/094413.736:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [09:44:13.736] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1058 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[13504:11156:0613/094413.739:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [09:44:13.739] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1058 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[13504:11156:0613/094419.378:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [09:44:19.378] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1058 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[13504:11156:0613/094419.383:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [09:44:19.383] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1058 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

How i can fix this

Comment: Instead of chrome_options try options = options in line 4

Comment: I'm try but this still error

Answer (score 0):

`chrome_options` has been deprecated

Instead of this :

```
drive = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\ggauto\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

do this :

```
drive = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\ggauto\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```

Comment: still error :( 
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61441/devtools/browser/80ff6f0f-c9f5-4923-bcbb-b974b18675e2
[3692:12080:0613/181407.536:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [18:14:07.536] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1058 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[3692:12080:0613/181407.539:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [18:14:07.539] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1058 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)